# Error install kubelet

Tags: kubernetes

I have a problem after I install finished, Try to run `kubelet version` got an error like that `error: failed to run Kubelet: Running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! or set --fail-swap-on flag to false. /proc/swaps contained`. I have disabled it but still got error the same

[image]

Comment: Well... Did you disable swap?

Comment: yes, I did but still got an error the same.

Comment: Did you restart the server (shutdown -r now) and also removed swap from /etc/fstab?

Answer (score 0):

Ansible

```
- name: swap - remove current swaps from fstab
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/fstab
    regexp: '^/[\S]+\s+none\s+swap '
    state: absent

- name: Restart server
  command: /sbin/shutdown -r 1
  async: 0
  poll: 0
  ignore_errors: true

- pause:
    prompt: "The system has restarted to complete disabling swap (otherwise error with kubeadm)..."
    minutes: 1
```